# Why is the "thirsty" method on my class not working?

Tags: javascript

I'm not sure why the method thirsty isn't returning true. Not a lot more else to say, but the function itself seems fine to me yet throws a type error.

```
  class Vampire {
        constructor(name, pet) {
            this.name = name;
            if (pet === undefined) {
                this.pet = 'bat';
            } else {
                this.pet = pet;
            }
        }
        thirsty() {
            return true
        };
    }
```

it is failing this test:

```
  it('should have vampire return true if thirsty', function() {
    var vampire = new Vampire('Andy');
    assert.equal(vampire.thirsty, true);
  });
```

Comment: `yet throws a type error.` What exactly does the error say? How are you using this class?

Comment: I cannot recreate your error. Seems to work fine `console.log(new Vampire('a', 'b').thirsty())`

Comment: @tkausl `Uncaught TypeError: Vampire.thirsty is not a function at <anonymous>:1:9` it's just for a "challenge" I'm doing where it just asks me to make a method called thirsty that returns true if called.

Comment: So you haven't actually created a (instance of) Vampire?

Comment: @tkausl sorry, yes I wasnt paying attention ... it does work when I create an instance of it ... for some reason it doesnt work in this mocha/chai testing thing I need to run it through... oh well.

Comment: Post your test then @kevin

Comment: @FrankerZ its been updated

Comment: @kevin See my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine, as long as you create a new instance of your class:

```js
class Vampire {
    constructor(name, pet) {
        this.name = name;
        if (pet === undefined) {
            this.pet = 'bat';
        } else {
            this.pet = pet;
        }
    }
    thirsty() {
        return true
    };
}

var pet = new Vampire('boo');

console.log(pet.thirsty());
```

Perhaps you were trying to access it like `Vampire.thirsty()`? If that's the case, you should make it a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

```js
class Vampire {
    constructor(name, pet) {
        this.name = name;
        if (pet === undefined) {
            this.pet = 'bat';
        } else {
            this.pet = pet;
        }
    }
    static thirsty() {
        return true
    };
}

console.log(Vampire.thirsty());
```

**EDIT:** The problem with your test, is you're testing `thirsty`, and not `thirsty()`. `thirsty` is a function, and calling the function will return true. Simply update your test, to actually call `thirsty`:

```
it('should have vampire return true if thirsty', function() {
  var vampire = new Vampire('Andy');
  assert.equal(vampire.thirsty(), true);
});
```

Comment: Ah, yes I tried making it property as well ... that slipped right past me... Thanks for the help!

Comment: When in doubt, `console.log()` the variable. You'll see that `vampire.thirsty` is a function, and not true, and that should signal a problem with how you're calling it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call `Vampire.thirsty` like this because `thirsty` isn't a *static* method. You either need to create a new instance of your `class`, or declare your `thirsty` method as *static*:

*Static* way:

```js
class Vampire {
  constructor(name, pet) {
    this.name = name;
    if (pet === undefined) {
      this.pet = 'bat';
    } else {
      this.pet = pet;
    }
  }
  static thirsty() { // declare as static
    return true
  };
}

console.log(Vampire.thirsty());
```

*new instance* way (use round brackets to call the method itself: `thirsty()`):

```js
class Vampire {
  constructor(name, pet) {
    this.name = name;
    if (pet === undefined) {
      this.pet = 'bat';
    } else {
      this.pet = pet;
    }
  }
  thirsty() { // declare as static
    return true
  };
}

let vlad = new Vampire("Vlad", "dog"); // create an instance of the class Vampire (an object)
console.log(vlad.thirsty()); // call the thirsy method on the object (ensure you use the round brackets ())
```

Comment: Silly Nick, Poor Vlad is a dog, not a vampire.

Comment: @FrankerZ He's a vampire called Vlad, with a pet dog :P

Answer (score 0):

In your test, you are incorrectly comparing the function `thirsty` and `true`.

`assert.equal(vampire.thirsty, true);`

You are not invoking `thirsty` and checking the return value.

You need to call the method like this:

`assert.equal(vampire.thirsty(), true);`